# survival::tmerge: how to manage events that are actually not not be intended as multiple?

Tags: r, tidyverse, survival

I'm struggling to set a dataframe for multistate survival analysis. Here is the reproducible example with only 3 individuals (ID). This is only a part of the multistate.

```
f <- structure(list(ID = c(3, 4, 5), time_to_end = c(30, 36, 36)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

f.long<–structure(list(ID = c(3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5), resp_pois = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), time = c(6, 12, 18, 24, 30, 36, 42, 48, 6, 12, 18, 24, 30, 36, 42, 48, 6, 
12, 18, 24, 30, 36, 42, 48)), row.names = c(NA, -24L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

f includes 3 individual taking a new drug and observed for time_to_end.
f.long includes the biochemical response at different time points.
E.g., ID 3 immediately respond to the drug up to 24 months, but at 30 months there is evidence of lack of biochemical response, while ID 4 shows only an isolated response at 24 months but never again or before.

I'm trying to manage this reversible condition between response and no-response with tmerge, as follows:

```
f.merge <- tmerge(f %>% select(ID), f, id=ID, tstart = 0, tstop = time_to_end)
f.merge <- tmerge(f.merge, f.long, id=ID, response=event(time, resp_pois))
survfit(Surv(tstart, tstop, response)~1, data=f.merge)
```

The problem is that tmerge interpretes every resp==1 as a new event, so at the end the survfit function give 5, instead of 2.

Can someone suggest any solution? Am i probably misusing tmerge?

Answer (score 0):

I got this answer from Prof Terry Therneau by e-mail

> Okay,
> 0.  When debugging a purported issue with the survival package, my first step is run in an R session with the survival package loaded, and NOTHING else.
>
> 1. I can't read your data set: I'm getting a syntax error somewhere.    But by cutting and pasting, I was able to create a "de tibbled" version of the data.
> 2. But what exactly is the data?  The variable name "resp_pois" means nothing to me.    You gave some information on where you want to go, but none about where you are starting.      I will hazard a guess that you are dealing with panel data, i.e., subjects come in at regular intervals and you mesure their state at each visit?
> 3. Now, tmerge has no way to distinguish a data set with multiple heart attacks, and one row per attack; from a panel study data set.

Comment: Those comments seems to be useful to improve your question, but not an answer for that. Could you please adjust your question accordingly and delete the answer?